# Define translations inside directives

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I want to build directives with each having their own translation. All I seem to find is a way to "globally" set all of the translations (via `app.config($translateProvider)`) or a custom loader which seems kind of overkill.
Unfortunately I can't inject $translateProvider into a directive (is that normal?) which would be exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Providers while running the app already. You can use either the `translationProvider.translations()` method or you have to use asynchronous loaders, details can be found [in this GitHub issue.](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/930)

*An excerpt on Providers:*
The [Angular Documentation for Providers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) states:

> You should use the Provider recipe only when you want to expose an API for application-wide configuration that must be made before the application starts.

For a better understanding, read [this article](http://benclinkinbeard.com/posts/creating-configurable-angular-directives-with-providers/) from Ben Clinkinbeard. It shows you, how you to access a provider's properties (in this case the locale property) inside a directive and how to configure the locale inside a config function (which is run before the application has "started" (this is the so called configuration phase) - this means, the locale is already set in your provider if your directive code runs). I also recommend looking into  [Ben's example repository](https://github.com/bclinkinbeard/demo-directives-with-providers).

Notice the use of the **bilingualButtonConfig** inside the directive, but the use **bilingualButtonConfigProvider** inside the .config()-function during configuration phase.

If the configuration phase is over - access to providers is denied. Then services get created and the application goes over to the run phase. And that is your problem. You try to access the providers in the run phase - which angular denies.